# How can I sum vectors nested in a column of a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame where one column contains a list.  I want to convert the list to numeric and sum the values into a new column.  Each row has a column with a vector like this:

```
c("47", "39", "1")
```

The new column would contain the sum of those numbers and would look like this:

```
List                  SumList
c("47", "39", "1")     87
c("11", "11")          22
c("1", "2")             3
```

I have tried a couple different approaches, but nothing seems to produce the outcome I need.

Example data frame:

```
DF <- structure(list(list = structure(list(c("47", "39", "1"), c("11", 
"11"), c("1", "2")))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Fyi, it's generally a good idea to include code that reproduces your example data. Your post has been edited to include the best guess anyone has, though we can't be sure it's right.

Comment: Apologies.  Will make sure to include sample next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want using the dplyr functions rowwise and mutate.

Example:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(List = list(c("47", "39", "1"), c("11","11"), c("1","2"))) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(SumList = sum(as.numeric(List)))
```

Answer (score 3):

**1)** Assuming the data frame in the Note at the end, try the following code.  No packages are used.

```
transform(DF, sum = sapply(list, function(x) sum(as.numeric(x))))
```

giving:

```
       list sum
1 47, 39, 1  87
2    11, 11  22
3      1, 2   3
```

**2)** Another approach is to convert `DF` to a long form and then sum that giving the same result.  Again no packages are used.

```
long <- stack(setNames(DF$list, seq_along(DF$list)))
transform(DF, sum = rowsum(as.numeric(long$value), long$ind))
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
DF <- structure(list(list = structure(list(c("47", "39", "1"), c("11", 
"11"), c("1", "2")))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `purrr` solution that uses `map_dbl`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(purrr)

tibble(x = list(c("47", "39", "1"), c("11","11"), c("1","2"))) %>% 
  mutate(Sum = map_dbl(x, function(i)sum(as.numeric(i))))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   x           Sum
#>   <list>    <dbl>
#> 1 <chr [3]>    87
#> 2 <chr [2]>    22
#> 3 <chr [2]>     3
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Supposing we use G. Grothendieck structure:

```
DF <- structure(list(list = structure(list(c("47", "39", "1"), c("11", 
                                                                 "11"), c("1", "2")))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

DF$SumList <-lapply(1:nrow(DF), function(x) sum(as.double(unlist(DF$list[x]))))
```

And with Frank input:

```
DF$SumList <-lapply(1:nrow(DF), function(x) sum(as.double(DF$list[[x]])))
```