# Is there an R function to multiply two columns contain vectors in a data frame together?

Tags: r, multiple-columns

I have two data frames and I'm asked to calculate the sub-total before discount. I tried to multiply Prices column with Quantities column from the first data frame and then add Delivery Fee from second data frame with R code

```
Order <- transform(
  Order,
  Sub_Total_Before_Discount=((raw$Prices * raw$Quantities) + Order$Delivery_Fee)
)
```

and it returns error

```
Error in raw$Prices * raw$Quantities : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I'm still new to R so please help me if there's any way to calculate this. Thank you so much.

[image: 1st data frame]

[image: 2nd data frame]

Comment: Have you confirmed if both columns are numeric, because the error tells you one column is not numeric. Use ```as.numeric()``` to change all columns to numeric

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

column bind both dataframes

```
df = cbind(dataframe1, dataframe2)
```

Change both columns to numeric

```
raw$Prices = as.numeric(unlist(raw$Prices))
raw$Quantities = as.numeric(unlist(raw$Quantities))
Order$Delivery_Fee = as.numeric(unlist(Order$Delivery_Fee))
```

Multiply columns with dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% mutate(order = Prices * Quantities)
```

final result

```
df$final_price <- df$order + df$Delivery_Fee
```

Comment: I tried to convert raw$Prices to numeric but it returns error: Error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'. I think it's because my price  column contain vectors in it. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @newt335 Without working dataset, I can't know what you are trying to do but  use ```unlist()``` before converting to numeric. I have edited code above on how to unlist

Comment: I tried `raw$Prices = as.numeric(unlist(raw$Prices))` but it returns error  `$<-.data.frame(`*tmp*`, Quantities, value = c(2, 1, 1, 3, 3,  : 
  replacement has 11430 rows, data has 5000`

Comment: @newt335 look at this, hope it can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55267688/how-can-i-sum-vectors-nested-in-a-column-of-a-data-frame